# how to display the values of the means in R ggdensity function?

Tags: r, addition, mean

any idea how to display the values of the dash lines (means) in the graphic below?

Thank you very much.

```
library(ggpubr)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
#> Loading required package: magrittr
# Create some data format
# :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
set.seed(1234)
wdata = data.frame(
   sex = factor(rep(c("F", "M"), each=200)),
   weight = c(rnorm(200, 55), rnorm(200, 58)))
head(wdata, 4)
#>   sex   weight
#> 1   F 53.79293
#> 2   F 55.27743
#> 3   F 56.08444
#> 4   F 52.65430

# Density plot with mean lines and marginal rug
# :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
# Change outline and fill colors by groups ("sex")
# Use custom palette
ggdensity(wdata, x = "weight",
   add = "mean", rug = TRUE,
   color = "sex", fill = "sex",
   palette = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the mean of each group by using `aggregate` and use this output to feed `geom_text` function:

```r
aggregate(weight~sex, data = wdata, FUN = mean)

  sex   weight
1   F 54.94224
2   M 58.07325
```

And here its use inside `geom_text`:

```r
ggdensity(wdata, x = "weight",
          add = "mean", rug = TRUE,
          color = "sex", fill = "sex",
          palette = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800"))+
  geom_text(data = aggregate(weight~sex, data = wdata, FUN = mean),
            aes(x = weight, y = Inf, color = sex, label = round(weight,2)), 
            vjust = 1)
```

[image]

Does it answer your question ?

Comment: Hi, dc37 yes it does, one day of my life lost in this... 
but finally, thanks to you all ok!

Thank you very much once again ;)
Best regards.

Comment: Done I believe, all the best dc37 ;)